# Java depth-first recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, graph-theory

Im writing a recursive function in Java (graph theory) to get all paths in a 4x4 table, beginning at a random starting point. Possible directions are horizontal, vertical & diagonal, but I have a requirement that the same location cannot be visited twice.

The script works fine so far, I get a lot of combinations. The problem is that in the for loop of the function, when there is more than one possible way, then I get wrong results in the second and following loops because the boolean[] tempvisited is not getting back to his old values.

I hope there is someone, that may understand my English and my problem too. Here is my code so far:

```
// here I define a constant input of values:
String letters = "1548987425461854"

// This matrix shows all possible directions from every startpoint in the matrix:
// from the second value, you may get to the following locations: 1,3,5,6 and 7
    private int[][] matrix = {
        {1,4,5},
        {0,2,4,5,6},
        {1,3,5,6,7},
        {2,6,7},
        {0,1,5,8,9},
        {0,1,2,4,6,8,9,10},
        {1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11},
        {2,3,6,10,11},
        {4,5,9,12,13},
        {4,5,6,8,10,12,13,14},
        {5,6,7,9,11,13,14,15},
        {6,7,10,14,15},
        {8,9,13},
        {8,9,10,12,14},
        {9,10,11,13,15},
        {10,11,14}
};

// Here begins the recursive function 
public List<Combination> depthFirst(int vertex, boolean[] visited, Combination zeichen, List<Combination> combis){
  // A temporary list of booleans to mark every value position visited or not
  boolean[] tempvisited = new boolean[16];

  // combis is the whole list of ways, zeichen is just the actual combination
  zeichen.name = zeichen.name + this.letters.charAt(vertex);
  combis.add(zeichen.name);

    //marks actual value as visited
    visited[vertex] = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        tempvisited[i] = visited[i];
    }//end for

    // going to next possible locations
    for (int i = 0; i < this.matrix[vertex].length; i++) {
        if (!visited[this.matrix[vertex][i]]) {         
            combis = depthFirst(this.matrix[vertex][i], tempvisited, zeichen, combis);      
        }//end if
    }//end for
    return combis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with `tempvisited`, making a copy.  But you're doing so in the wrong place.

You're setting `visited[vertex] = true`, which means that the `visited` you passed in is changing.  What you want is for `visited` to never change.  Make a copy of it, and make your changes to that copy.

Also, I notice that you use the same `zeichen` every time.  So if you have a path 3 steps long, your `combis` list with be 3 copies of the same `zeichen`.  That seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You set visited[vertex] to true before the first for loop; you could reset it to false just before you return.  If every call undoes the change it did (directly), then every call will return with visited back to its state when that call was made.  No tempvisited needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this other recursive solution (pseudocode) for the Depth First Search (DFS).

```
void search(Node root) {
 if (root == null) return;

 visit(root);
 root.visited = true;
 foreach (Node n in root.adjacent) {
  if (n.visited == false)
   search(n);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a copy of the visited array. Mark the node as visited right before the reccurrent call of depthFirst and then "unmark" it right after the call. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.matrix[vertex].length; i++) {
    if (!visited[this.matrix[vertex][i]]) {     
        visited[this.matrix[vertex][i]] = true;  
        combis = depthFirst(this.matrix[vertex][i], tempvisited, zeichen, combis);      
        visited[this.matrix[vertex][i]] = false;
    }//end if
}//end for
```

Comment: hmm thanks, but this slows down the script a lot and ends in a out of memory error